# Schedule a job for one time using angular-cron-jobs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js and using [angular-cron-jobs](https://github.com/angular-cron-jobs/angular-cron-jobs). While it provides option to schedule a job every minute, hour, day etc. I am unable to figure out how to schedule a job for one time (e.g. schedule it right now) using angular-cron-jobs? Can someone please help?

Comment: Why can't you just run what you need outside of angular-cron-jobs ?

Comment: So, I am using it as a configuration tool from UI. I need to configure multiple jobs for which this library is helpful. But I also need a "run now" kind of option so that I can configure and run the job one time. Do you have any clue about that? Else, I think I will have to give a check box sort of option only.